# Is there any data dictionary object in oracle to record the transaction details of triggers?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have created trigger TEST_TRIG as below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TEST_TRIG
   AFTER INSERT ON TEST_TABLE
   FOR EACH ROW
 DECLARE
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
 BEGIN
   TEST_PROC();
 END;
```

Procedure  TEST_PROC code:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE TEST_PROC 
AS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'truncate table TEST_FINAL';
  INSERT INTO TEST_FINAL select * from TEST_TABLE;
  commit;
END;
```

---

Initially, I disabled TRIGGER TEST_TRIG and inserted a record into TEST_TABLE and executed  PROCEDURE TEST_PROC manually.

Output: I was able to fetch the same record what i inserted into TEST_TABLE from TEST_FINAL.

---

I flushed those records from both table and enabled the trigger TEST_TRIG.

Now when i inserts and commits the record in TEST_TABLE, I didn't found the record in TEST_FINAL table... I haven't received any error message also!!!

So I want to know whether trigger got fired or not?

Comment: since this is just a test for you, why not put a dbms_output.put_line("fired!") in the test_proc?

Comment: @tbone: i have made changes & tested .... I got output as FIRED! ... but still i confused y data is not inserted in TEST_FINAL table!!???

Comment: did you set serveroutput on?  where are you running these tests? (what ide? toad, sql developer, sqlplus?)

Comment: in sqldeveloper ... before i didn't set server output on... now i made it & getting output as FIRED! but still i am not able to see any data in TEST_FINAL table... Y!??

Comment: Why would you want to truncate `TEST_FINAL` ***every time*** a row is instered into `TEST_TABLE`? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: see APC's answer.  Basically your trigger is autonomous and can't see the rows you just inserted.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: thank u.. ya i agree .. i ll remove it from code...

Comment: @APC >> u have given a clear idea about AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION.. thanks a lot... i ll start working on code ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have fully grasped the implications of AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION.  Effectively it means the code bounded by the pragma runs in *a separate session* .  So, because of Oracle's read consistent isolation level, the autonomous transaction cannot see any of the data changes generated by the main transaction.

Thus, if TEST_TABLE is empty when you start the trigger will insert *no rows* into TEST_FINAL, regardless of how many rows you're inserting right now.

So: don't flush both tables.  Insert some rows into TEST_TABLE and commit.  TEST_FINAL will still be empty.  Insert some more rows  into TEST_TABLE and, lo! the first set of rows will appear in TEST_FINAL.

Obviously this is not the result you want.  So you need to revisit your logic.  It really doesn't make sense to truncate TEST_FINAL every time and definitely not FOR EACH ROW.  That is Teh Suck! as far as performance goes.  Likewise and for the same reason it doesn't make sense to populate the target table with INSERT ... SELECT .

Discarding the TRUNCATE means you don't need the pragma and everything becomes much simpler,

If you want to keep a history of the affected rows use something like this instead:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TEST_TRIG
   AFTER INSERT ON TEST_TABLE
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    insert into test_final (col1, col2)
    values (:new.col1, :new.col2);
END;
```

You'll need to change the exact code to fit your exact requirements.